# How do you iterate over a range of numbers with each do with/ ERB Ruby on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to iterate over a range of years for a method that passes on unique years to a where clause in ruby on rails. For some odd reason, it does not fire off when I attempt to pass those numbers down to the method chain. For starters, I am working on a reporting feature that tracks charts by years in between a range. For example: Search starts at 2020 and ends at 2024. All years from 2020 to 2024 will show a report for each year compiled together. Right now, I only get one year and I should be getting 2020, 2021 and 2024 on one response..How can I print out a range of years by integer and pass them through the each block to the corresponding method?

Example code below:

```
params {start_year: "2019", end_year: "2020"}

params[:start_year], params[:end_year]

<% [@start_year.to_i+1...@end_year.to_i].each do |facility_year| %>
   <% @facility.chart_records.where('extract(year from record_date) =?', facility_year).limit(11).each do |chart_record| %>
<tr>
<td><%= chart_record.record_date.strftime("%Y") %></td>
<td>Month: Jan</td>
<td><%= ChartRecord.where(facility_id: @facility.id).where('extract(month from record_date) =?', 1).where('extract(year from record_date) =?', facility_year).sum(:fit_jeans_count)</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I just want to get one unique year from the start_year+1 count up until the end_year count and then display one record for each year in the range..

Comment: Well, to start, you have some pretty glaring syntax errors here. To iterate over a range of numbers you would use parenthesis ex. `(1..10)`. You also have a space between `.limit(11).` and `each`, that won't work. And on top of all that, it seems like you're missing an `<% end %>` for one of the loops. I'm surprised the page isn't erroring out.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Please correct your code example so it is syntactically correct. Code must be the absolute minimum and runnable and demonstrate the problem _in the question itself_. If we can't duplicate the problem we can't do anything except try to fix your code and then come up with an answer, but that only answers the problem with our version of your code, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

For ranges use parentheses `(@start_year.to_i+1...@end_year.to_i)` not brackets.
With brackets, you create an array with only one item that contains a range. With parentheses, you'll get a range right away.

Comment: I tried that. But, it doesn't iterate over the numbers.

Comment: How do you check it? Strange it should not be lazy here. Try to convert it to an array  `(@start_year.to_i+1...@end_year.to_i).to_a.each`

Comment: @dw4050 and Yakov you have 3 periods there, it should be 2

Comment: Yes. `(2019+1...2020)` will give an empty array. Because `...` excludes the last item of the range. `(2019+1..2020)` will give an array with one item.

Comment: I will check again in my console and try again, shortly.